# handle window.open() while headless scraping

Tags: screen-scraping, window.open, phantomjs, headless

i have to hit the URL, http://judis.nic.in/supremecourt/chejudis.asp. submit a form here to get the page that is supposed to be scrapped.I am using PhantomJS and PJScrape . Issue is, after the form submit,  results show up in a new window. I have skimmed through phantomjs issue list and found windown.open can not be handled . Is there any other way/framework I could use here? 
I have to stick to headless scraping and i cant use Selenium etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject javascript in the page to monkey-patch window.open like that:

```
var log = {};
window.my_open = window.open;    
window.open=function (str1,str2,str3){
    console.log("** window.open ** " + str1 + " / " + str2 + " / " + str3);
    log.open = {"url":str1, "name":str2, "features":str3};
    var new_win =  this.my_open(str1, str2,str3);
    return new_win;
}
```

Then you can access the url from within PJS and keep scraping from there.

Note that new_win will be "undefined" because PJS doesn't implement it.